# Pass map, slice over channel and over network?

Tags: go, channel, distributed-system

What is the best way to pass slice and map structure over channel that is distributed over network? I need to distribute the application running over several `EC2` instances and wonder how I can achieve this by communicating each application by `Go` channel.

Here's the workflow that I would like to run:

```
1. Process data in one application
2. Distribute the data into 10 replica applications
3. Each 10 application does its job in a separate EC2 instance
4. Once they are all done, they send the result back to the original program
5. This is sent over the channel
```

Please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If depends on the format you will chose for the serialization.

One well-suited for over-the-network communication is [MessagePack](http://msgpack.org/) (an efficient binary serialization format. It lets you exchange data among multiple languages like JSON. But it's faster and smaller)

A Go library like [`philhofer/msgp`](https://github.com/philhofer/msgp) can serializaze any struct ([like one with a map](https://github.com/philhofer/msgp/blob/d138861927e637539c37e44fa314c1f8bb6b610d/parse/_to_parse.go#L3-L4)), including [composite types](https://github.com/philhofer/msgp/wiki/The-MessagePack-Type-System#composite-types) like maps and arrays.

However, it uses Go1.4 [`go generate` command](https://github.com/philhofer/msgp/wiki/Using-the-Code-Generator#using-the-generator-with-go-generate). (go 1.4rc1 is already out)

From there, a library like [**`docker/libchan`**](https://github.com/docker/libchan) can help: Libchan is an ultra-lightweight networking library which lets network services communicate in the same way that goroutines communicate using channels.

Comment: Thanks! Guess i am confused. What do you mean by serialization? Is it something that i need for over the network communication?

Comment: @cvxv31431asdas yes, encoding/decoding data from a struct. The serialization helps transforming a struct data into a string which can be pass over and decoded.

Comment: Oh so if i need to send data over network i need to encode the data

Comment: @cvxv31431asdas yes, that is the idea. After, I have added in the answer a suggestion for a library to actually send that encoded data over the network.